# Need to migrate/upgrade ui bootstrap from 0.12.1 to 2.1.1

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap-tab

I'm in need to upgrade / migrate UI Bootstrap from 0.12.1 to 2.1.1
Is there any smooth change over this?

Answer (score 1):

No!

The UI-Bootstrap github page has a migration guide you might want to look at.

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/wiki/Migration-guide-for-prefixes

Also, version 2 saw the removal of the `replace` attribute, so you will also have to refactor your HTML. refer to the changelog for version 2.0.0, look under `BREAKING CHANGES`

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-2016-07-20